# How to use runTransaction with firebase_database 9.0.3

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

Can anyone give where to look, or what I am missing, for how to use runTransaction in 9.0.3? (Flutter, Firebase realtime DB)
I updated firebase_database ^7.0.0 to ^9.0.3. Had to change runTransaction(MutableData mutable) to runTransaction(Object object), and the Object is null for Map data. Does return a String when point to single node of a String.

For something to work I placed + ‘/sap’ at end of .ref(…), and it gave ‘DROID’

Code Updated for Comment below:

````
    bool bCanWeStartGame = false;
    bool bIfiOS = false;
    bIfiOS = Theme.of(referencedData.mngGamesPageMaterialContext)
        .platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
    DatabaseReference playersRef = referencedData.database.ref(
        TABLENAME_STARTS + '/' + referencedData.strFBGameUniqueIDKey);

    if(bIfiOS){
      //apparently iPhone needs to 'open line to DB record' to work
      playersRef.once()
          .then((DatabaseEvent event) {//dont need to do anything??
      });
    }

    TransactionResult txResult;
    //while loop to repeat runTransaction until solved
    int iWhileLoopCheck = 0; //so whileLoop does not go forever
    bool bTransactionCommittedOrGetOutAnyWay = false;
    while(!bTransactionCommittedOrGetOutAnyWay
        && (iWhileLoopCheck<30)){
      iWhileLoopCheck++;
      txResult = await playersRef
          .runTransaction(
              (Object post) {
            if (post == null) {
              if(bIfiOS){sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 3));}
              return Transaction.abort(); //out, but will retry transaction
            }
            Map<String, dynamic> _post = Map<String, dynamic>.from(post as Map);

            bTransactionCommittedOrGetOutAnyWay = true; //whichever of
            //options below take effect, dont want to continue while loop
            if (_post[STARTS_TABLE_ALL_PLAYERS] !=
                startingGames[iIndexInStartingGames].allplayers) {
              //someone has joined since trying to start
              bCanWeStartGame = false;
              //Transaction.abort() as dont want to change data
              return Transaction.abort();
            } else {
              //Nobody has joined, so can Start. Tell others Game is starting
              _post['stg'] = true;
              bCanWeStartGame = true;
              return Transaction.success(_post);
            }
          });
    } //while runtransaction doesnot get at data```
````

Comment: I may be getting closer to an answer, but I still think I am missing something. I think the reason my example worked just to return the one DB entry was that I had done a read once, which, to my thinking, opened up the lines to the data. When I enclose the whole runTransaction inside a while (until transaction returns success), then the full set of data can be read in a transaction. I will do some more testing.

Comment: I got something to work. Although I still think i am missing something. I had to do a dummy read of the data at the start. I had to enclose the runTransaction() inside a While Loop. Typically on an Android (device or emulator) the While Loop ran 2 times before getting data in the Object. In iOS, it typically took 6 to 9 loops.

Comment: While the solution given above sort of works, it does depend on loops of up to 25, and even then there are failures. I think I have to write my own 'transaction'. My idea is to have a blank space. If a person want to join the game, that person writes to that space. Backs off, and if the 'code' written is still in that space, that person can join. If another person tried to join. If they see something, they cannot join. If they are able to write, then that first person would not see their code there anymore, so the 2nd person would be able to join. After joining, put a space back